# TL072 supply voltage +-4.5 V vs. +-9 V

Tags: power-supply

I have preamp circuit from an earlier project that is based on TL072 opamps. I have been using it with a 9 V (+-4.5 V) power supply, but now I have the chance to give it a +-9 V supply. The signal that goes through it is a small audio signal, probably never larger than 1 V. Does it make any sense to bother giving it a larger supply voltage? (I know that the minimum supply voltage for this IC is 7 V (+-3.5 V) by the datasheet.)

Comment: Need a schematic with gain to answer this question

Comment: That's too small a voltage for the TL072. If the signal you are processing is small, I would use a lower voltage rail to rail op amp.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tl074.pdf) I have for TI's TL07x series tells me that the minimum supply voltage is 10V(+-5V).
That, combined with the common-mode input range and max output swing, means that you're lucky your existing circuit works at all (and might not work if you drop in a different TL072 from a different production batch).

If you have 18V(+-9V) available I would definitely make use of it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It feels good to have been lucky :)

Answer (score 0):

TL7x work just fine at 4.5/9V (as used in countless guitar effects for decades without problems). As per the datasheet, the 10V min refers *only* to packages labelled NS or PS.

Comment: Thanks for deciding to share your knowledge with others.   In your answer you provide useful information about the voltage range of the TL072 part, but it looks like that information is in relation to another answer, rather than the question itself.  Suggest you either add this as a comment on the previous answer, and extend your own answer to also directly answer the question.  Have a read of https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer for some guidance.  Once again, welcome!